# How to convert a text file where data is separated by rows using ids, to an easy lookup (dictionary, json, etc.) preserving whitespacing/lines?

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like this

```
start_id=372
text: this is some    text with
vartions in


   white spacing and such
END_OF_RECORD

start_id=3453
text:      Continued for 

this record
   that has other


variations in whitespacing 
END_OF_RECORD
```

I need to convert this such that I can easily access the data with the preserved whitespacing and lines.

So something like this

```
result = function('start_id=3453')
result
```

returns

```
text:      Continued for 

this record
   that has other


variations in whitespacing
```

The reason I need to preserve the whitespacing is because I need to look stuff by span. So

```
result[11:14]
```

results in

```
Con
```

Strategies I have though up of:

I have an algorithm that goes down the lines and searches if the line starts with 'start_id'. When I do, I go down the line until I reach end of line or whitespace, and record this span into a dictionary key.
Then I go down the lines until I hit 'END_OF_RECORD'.
I then somehow copy the whole line span into the dictionary value for that key.

My concerns about this method if there are any edge cases I am not thinking of, and how to copy whole several lines into a python value.

Comment: If you read the whole file, you can do `s.split("END_OF_RECORD")`, and that will get you a list of records.  You can then process each record on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be actually quite simple if you use regex... something like this:

```
import re

dictionary_of_records = {} # records will be stored here
recording = False # this will allow me to prevent starting new record while recording and will hold the id

# matchers
start = re.compile(r'start_id=(\d*)')
end = re.compile(r'END_OF_RECORD')

with open('stack.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():

        if start.match(line):
            if recording:
                raise Exception('Attempting to create new record without ending previous one!')
            print('Start... matched!')
            recording = start.search(line).group(1) # save the id of recording
            print(f'Starting record with id {recording}')
            current_record_string = '' # make a empty string to save recording to
        elif end.match(line):
            print('End... matched!')
            dictionary_of_records[recording] = current_record_string # save the entry to dict
            recording = False # reset recording to False 
            continue
        elif not recording:
            continue
        else:
            current_record_string += line

print(dictionary_of_records)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
data = {}

for line in open('/content/deidentified-medical-text-1.0/id.text').readlines():
    if line.startswith('START_OF_RECORD='):
        id_ = line.strip().split('=')[1]
        lines = []
    elif line.startswith('||||END_OF_RECORD'):
        data[id_] = ''.join(lines)
        id_ = None
        lines = []
    elif id_:
        lines.append(line)
```

```
>>> data
{372: 'text: this is some    text with\nvartions in\n\n\n   white spacing and such\n',
 3453: 'text:      Continued for\n\nthis record\n   that has other\n\n\nvariations in whitespacing\n'}

>>> data[3453][11:14]
'Con'
```